# Connecting PCIE connectors to gigabyte gtx 770 2gb windforce

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, pci-express

I have got a **Gigabyte Gtx 770 2gb Windforce** 
[Image of GPU connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmwzx.jpg)

My PSU is Thermaltake litepower 550w  that has two 6+2 pin PCIE connectors . 
Out of those 6 pin connectors one 6 pin is ahead of the other . And out of two 2 pin connectors, one of those is ahead of the other.

What is the best way to connect the PSU with GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 6+2 pin PCI-E connectors are identical, they'll just be designed in a way that allows one to reach further in the event that someone has two PCI-E cards to power.

I'd be more concerned that your PSU might not provide enough power for your graphics card. The official recommendation for this card is:

> 600W (with one 6-pin and one 8-pin external power connectors)

Either way, you're going to need to use both of the 6+2 PCI-E connectors from your PSU.

Comment: I have measured power supply requirement for my total pc using PSU calculator. It says recommended PSU is 462W.